# como esperar una respuesta de usuario con async

Tags: python, python-3.7, asyncio

Tengo un programa que recorre una base de datos, cada entrada es una tarea que debe realizar con sus parametros, sin embargo algunas requieren de la interacción del usuario, el caso es que no sé como esperar un input del usuario sin bloquear el resto de la aplicación

en pseudocodigo

```
while queden_tareas and no_se_cancele:
    resultado = await ejecuta_tarea()
    evalua(resultado)
```

el input viene de la consola ahora mismo con prompt toolkit, pero quiero cambiarlo a algo externo

ahora mismo la entrada del usuario esta así:

```
async def MANUAL(*args, **kargs):
    result = pts.yes_no_dialog(
        title='Por favor responda a la pregunta',
        text=f'# {current_test.prueba}\n{current_test.texto_manual}',
        yes_text='Aceptar',
        no_text='Cancelar'
        )
```

Answer (score 2):

En el paquete [aioconsole](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole) tienes el método [ainput](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aioconsole/blob/master/aioconsole/stream.py#L181), que puedes usar por ejemplo así:

```
from aioconsole import ainput

async def yes_no_input(prompt, yes, no):
    ans = ""
    while ans.upper() not in [yes, no]:
        ans = await ainput(prompt)
    if ans.upper() == yes:
        return True
    else:
        return False


async def MANUAL(*args, **kwargs):
    prompt = (
        "Por favor responda a la pregunta\n"
        f"# {current_test.prueba}\n"
        f"{current_test.texto_manual}\n"
        "(A)ceptar/(C)ancelar: "
    )
    result = await yes_no_input(prompt, "A", "C")
```

No obstante tendrías que pensar las implicaciones. ¿Puedes tener dos tareas manuales a la vez? No tengo claro qué ocurrirá en ese caso si se intentan ejecutar dos instancias concurrentes de `ainput`.

Comment: por como funciona la aplicación no se va a dar el caso de preguntar dos veces, cada tarea hace varias cosas pero las tareas en si son secuenciales, no se hacen dos a la vez, de todos modos, tras ver el paquete, no es lo que busco

Comment: Ya, pero si son asíncronas... en el momento en que haces `await` esa tarea queda "esperando" por la consiguiente entrada, pero el flujo de ejecución entretanto pasa a otra tarea. Si la otra tarea depende de algún modo de la entrada de la anterior no va a funcionar. Y si son puramente secuenciales (es decir, solo hay una tarea activa de cada vez) entonces el flujo es esencialmente síncrono ¿por qué usar async?

Comment: el flujo de trabajo es sincrono (las tareas) pero lo que hacen las tareas y otras cosas alrededor no